# delphi 2009 ClientDataSet.ApplyUpdates(-1) reutrns 3457496 on 10 rows processing

Tags: delphi, error-handling, delphi-2009, tclientdataset

running the code under a transatction then calling applayUpdates, and caching the errors to fix them. but the reconsile code that worked in delphi 7, goes to infinite loop on delphi 2009.

```
table1.Connection.BeginTrans;
//some code
repeat
  try
    numberOfErrors := table2.ApplyUpdates(-1); // here the returned value in delphi 2009 is 3457496 why?
    if (numberOfErrors > 0) then
      fixValuesTable2;
  Except
    fixValuesTable2;
  end;
until numberOfErrors=0;

table1.Connection.CommitTrans;
```

table1 and table2 share connection.

was the ClientDataSet changed in the use convetion over the couse of delphi 7 to delphi 2009?

the provider is TDataSetProvider which is connected to ado componenet to mssql database

Comment: ADO ErrorValueEnum gives you the code of the error http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677004%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: get the description by calling ADOConnection1.Errors.Item[ADOConnection1.Errors.Count-1].Description

Comment: That's not how you use TClientDataset (and provider) to handle transactions and errors. AFAIK a provider already starts a transaction to apply updates - unless you manage the updates yourself in a BeforeUpdateRecord event. And update errors are better handle in an OnReconcileError event. Why it returns that value I do not know - no enough info to determine if it is right or wrong. Your code is not good, anyway - and you swallow any exception without trying to understand if it is due to values in table2 or something else.

Comment: @RBA: a Delphi TClientDataset doesn't return an error code because it can update more than one record in a single call - it returns the number of errors encountered. The OP should implement the proper events to check for and resolve (if possible) each record, where he will find the error condition for the given record.

Comment: @RBA from the manual: "ApplyUpdates returns the number of errors it encountered." so it is not suppose to be an error number, rather a row count number which didn't pass. i would expect the manual to remove the s to match what you say

Comment: @MadHatter the problem is i don't know how to handle the errors. there is a conflict in keys, and the update,in the reconcile event, does not "stick" it just revert to the old value, no matter what "action" is chosen raSkip (this should not revert), raCurrect(this should revert).

Comment: @none: how did you implement the error handling? There are subtle and little documented ways to perform it correctly. Anyway if you have conflict in keys you should first fix the logic that generates them, instead of attempting to fix them later.